# Extend Windows screen recording time past limit

Tags: windows-10, screen-recorder

I have been using the Windows 10 'xbox' screen recording feature on my laptop a couple times and have been hitting the 2 hour recording limit. I found that I could go into my machine's settings and set the limit to as high as 4 hours, but ideally I would like to go as high as 12. I saw lots of people online who did not have this 4 hour option. Do machines with more memory or disk space have options greater than 4 hours? Is there a system registry file or something that I can edit to add more options to the settings?

Below is an example of what the maximum recording times are:
[image: pic of current dropdown options here]

Comment: I am not currently on my Windows 10 machine, so I can't tell you for sure.
But as I recall there should be an option to record the entire session that you have your game running (this is because when opening a game, Windows 10 (with xbox) turns on a gaming mode which tells the recorder to start recording).
So if you are using the recorder to record your game, you should be able to do it that way (you have to turn on the option for recording in the background)

Comment: Okay, so I just saw that your screenshot shows that option that I was talking about... "Background Recording" what options are there when you turn that on?

Comment: That affects a different feature; the ability to always record the last 30 seconds, 1 minute, etc. even if you weren't explicitly recording (so you can save that time frame in case something interesting just happened in your game). I tried enabling it, but it had no effect on the options I was concerned with.